# Fail to start services because of selinux Permission Denied

Tags: fedora, selinux

Can't start few services because of strange selinux Permission Denied on fresh Fedora 32 installation.

```
  UNIT                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                   
● fprintd.service           loaded failed failed Fingerprint Authentication Dae
● systemd-hostnamed.service loaded failed failed Hostname Service              
● systemd-localed.service   loaded failed failed Locale Service                
● systemd-timedated.service loaded failed failed Time & Date Service
```

Example of logs when try to start systemd-hostnamed:

```
Sep 02 21:25:26 uragan systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-hostnamed.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit systemd-hostnamed.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2907.
Sep 02 21:25:26 uragan audit[4860]: AVC avc:  denied  { remount } for  pid=4860 comm="(ostnamed)" scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=0
Sep 02 21:25:26 uragan systemd[4860]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/: Permission denied
Sep 02 21:25:26 uragan systemd[4860]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-hostnamed: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-hostnamed could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-hostnamed could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is ERRNO.
Sep 02 21:25:26 uragan systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit systemd-hostnamed.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 226.
Sep 02 21:25:26 uragan systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The unit systemd-hostnamed.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 02 21:25:26 uragan systemd[1]: Failed to start Hostname Service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-hostnamed.service has failed
```

UPDATE:

Looks like it is caused by mounted exfat from USB microsd card reader. As fast as I do manual unmount this exfat, without removing the reader from the USB port, as fast I'm able to start systemd-hostnamed service.
When replug the reader, automount does mount of the exfat and systemd-hostnamed fails and stop.
Anyone faced it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the reason. Looks like a bug in Fedora or kernel in the area of exfat mount.
When exfat is automounted then services fail and can't start anymore. After umount of the exfat, even without removing the drive from the USB port, I'm able to start those services immediately.
What is worth to mention if rpmfusion packages 'fuse-exfat' and 'exfat-utils' are installed then the issue does not occur. The only difference is that without those two packages installed during mount process below message can be found in journalctl:

```
exfat: Deprecated parameter 'namecase'
```

The issue has been reported to redhat bugzilla: [Bug 1875064](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1875064)